# Get option value when changing option in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, laravel

I need to update `rate` text box when user selecting from `master_items`. How it is possible,

HTML,

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in quotation.items track by $index">
            <td>
                <select ng-model="item.item" ng-options="master_item.name as master_item.name for master_item in master_items" class="form-control" ng-change="updateItem(master_item.rate,$index)"></select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text"  step="any" min="0" max="99999999" class="form-control" ng-model="item.quantity" placeholder="Quantity" required/></td>
            <td><input type="text"  step="any" min="0" max="99999999" class="form-control" ng-model="item.rate" placeholder="Rate" required /></td>
            <td><input type="text"  step="any" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" value="{{item.quantity * item.rate}}" disabled/></td>
            <th><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-if="$index > 0" ng-click="removeInputElement($index)"><i class="fa fa-remove red"></i></a></th>
        </tr>
```

Here,when user select an option from master items,I want to update corresponding rate field.Here select box is working fine and each options has correct value,but I dont know how can I get selected option value.

My `master_items` `JSON` is,

```
    {
        "total": 5,
        "per_page": 100,
        "current_page": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "next_page_url": null,
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "from": 1,
        "to": 5,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 63,
                "name": "Lumia 6252",
                "description": null,
                "unit": null,
                "rate": "12.00",
                "created_by": 0,
                "updated_by": null,
                "delete_by": null,
                "created_at": "2015-03-15 17:38:40",
                "updated_at": "2015-03-15 17:38:40",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "status": 1
            }
}
```

[image: Item list screenshot].

Comment: `code is not working` ... what code? All you have shown is data. You need to show the problem code

Comment: I updated..now it is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<select ng-model="item.item" ng-options="master_item.name as master_item.name for master_item in master_items" class="form-control" ng-change="updateItem(this,$index)"></select>


$scope.updateItem=function(data,index)
{
var abjValue= data.item.item.name// You can see with quick watch for what value return from this name
}
```

Comment: data.item returns item name,not object. so I am not able to access like data.item.item.rate..

Comment: it's a solution for how to get a selected ddl value :) thanks

Comment: I want to get rate when user select an item and update that rate to corresponding rate textbox..any idea?